# Perl, how to avoid diagnostic messages from not-directly included modules?

Tags: perl, diagnostics, www-mechanize

I'm getting this warning (after "use diagnostics;");

***Parsing of undecoded UTF-8 will give garbage when decoding entities at /usr/lib/perl5/HTML/PullParser.pm line 81.***

My program is like this:

```
...
use diagnostics;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::Gzip;
...

$m = WWW::Mechanize::GZip->new(
 agent => $self->{_agent},
 timeout => $self->{_timeout},
);

if (!$m->get($url)) {
 die("Impossibile scaricare l'url [$url]");
}
if (!$m->form_number(1)) {
 die("Impossibile trovare il form 1");
}

 <WARNING IS EMITTED HERE>

...
```

How to I get rid of it? Or may I safely ignore it?

**UPDATE:**
I just dotice that using WWW::Mechanize->new() insted of WWW::Mechanize::GZip->new() does work silently... So the problem comes from the GZip module...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the question you're asking really is the wrong one. **You don't want to suppress those warnings, you want to prevent them**.

This sounds like WWW::Mechanize::Gzip is buggy. You don't really need it anyway, LWP has gzip support built in. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285305/how-can-i-accept-gzip-compressed-content-using-lwpuseragent) (WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent) for an explanation on how to achieve similar results in a more sane way.

Comment: I see. Thanks. You are right, I do not want to suppress any warnings, I would like to understand where do they come from... But, how do I fill a form fields and submit it with LWP::UserAgent?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to drop WWW::Mechanize…

Comment: I see... You suggest to use WWW::Mechanize instaed of WWW::Mechanize::Gzip, and handle zipped content using LWP, right?